# How to combine two strings in Objective-C for an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos

How can I combine "stringURL" and "stringSearch" together?

```
- (IBAction)search:(id)sender;{
stringURL = @"http://www.websitehere.com/index.php?s=";
stringSearch = search.text;
/* Something such as:
 stringURL_ = stringURL + stringSearch */
[web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL_]]];
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Philippe gave a good example.

You can also use plain `stringWithFormat`: method.

```
NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", stringURL, stringSearch];
```

This way you can manipulate string even more by putting somethig inbetween the strings like:

```
NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/someMethod.php?%@", stringURL, stringSearch];
```

Comment: Thanks! I like this way better, it does give you more control. I will definitely use it in the future! But for what I wanted to do stringByAppendingString worked fine.

Answer (score 17):

```
NSString* combinedString = [stringUrl stringByAppendingString: search.text];
```

Answer (score 6):

`NSString * combined = [stringURL stringByAppendingString:stringSearch];`

Comment: Thanks so much! I am brand new to this site but I will "vote up" as soon as I am able!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `stringByAppendingString:`, you could also use

```
NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", 
                                 stringURL, stringSearch];
```

This is especially interesting/convenient if you have more than one string to append. Otherwise, the `stringbyAppendingString:` method is probably the better choice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use stringByAppendingString:

```
 stringURL = [@"http://www.websitehere.com/index.php?s=" 
                      stringByAppendingString:search.text];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have some control about the format of the parameter you should assemble 
your URL string with

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.websitehere.com/index.php?s=%@", search.text]
```

This solution is charming because you can append almost anything which can be inserted into a printf-style format.

Answer (score 1):

I would not have given the answer of such general question.
There are many answers of same type question have already given. First find the answer of your question from existing question.

```
NSString* myURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.websitehere.com/index.php?s=%@", search.text];
```